# Send file to android device 4+ without selection picker

Tags: android, bluetooth

Good morning,

I'm newer in android I'm working on my android project I would like to send file to a specific device, I already got the bluetooth device so I don't need to use an Intent I just need to send selected file to the device. I make some research and I try to use Bluetooth share but this dont work on device 4+ because the exception is that I need `grantUriPermission`
My question is how to set this `granturiPermission`? Is there any method to send items automatically to a device without user interaction?

Here are code that I try :

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
             values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, uri.getPath());
             values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress());
             values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION,  BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
             Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
             values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
```

I try do use intent like this

```
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

     sharingIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);

    PackageManager pm = Manager.this.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities( sharingIntent, 0);
    String packageName = "";
    String mclassName = "";
    if(appsList.size() > 0 ){


        for(ResolveInfo info: appsList){
            packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
            if( packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")){
                mclassName = info.activityInfo.name;

                break;
            }
        }

    }



    sharingIntent.setClassName(packageName, className);
        sendBroadcast(sharingIntent);
```

But no reaction no exception but datas was not sent

Thank you for any advice